# dispatchKeyEvent does not trigger in Unity - Native Android plugin

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, native

I want to trigger onKeyUp or dispatchKeyEvent in Android, and send a message to Unity3D of the keyPress

I made a Java native Plugin with:

```
public class VolumeKeyClass extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d("Unity","onKeyUp UP");
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d("test", "Volume UP pressed! " + event);
             UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("MainController","logStatus","Volume up!!");
                }
                return true;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d("test", "Volume DOWN pressed! " + event);
                    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("MainController","logStatus","Volume Down!");
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Already Tested the communication, between Unity and The plugin, is correctly loggin the message, but onKeyUp nor dispatchKeyEvent is not triggering to send the message, nor the Logcat. (target API 15, Ice Cream Sandwich)

Comment: You need to register the event with a "+=".  See following : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15115/how-to-set-button-onclick-event-handler-declaratively

Comment: AJO = new AndroidJavaObject("com.company.volumekeyslibrary.VolumeKeyClass");
in the Start() of my main script. In the plugin constructor i have a thread execution to send a keep alive message to unity.

Comment: Please [edit] all information into the question, instead of hiding it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **OnKeyListener** like this:

```
   public class VolumeKeyClass extends Activity {

        void InitializeKeyListener ()
        {
           OnKeyListener keyListener = new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.d("Unity","onKeyUp UP");
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Log.d("test", "Volume UP pressed! " + event);
                 UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("MainController","logStatus","Volume up!!");
                    }
                    return true;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Log.d("test", "Volume DOWN pressed! " + event);
                        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("MainController","logStatus","Volume Down!");
                    }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
           };
        }
    }
```